# Instance name not working

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs4

My code looks like this

```
var newFrame:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
newFrame.graphics.lineStyle(lineWidth, xmlData.config.frame.@color);
newFrame.graphics.beginFill(0x000000, 0);
newFrame.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, stage.stageWidth+2, stage.stageHeight+2);
newFrame.graphics.endFill();
newFrame.name = "movieFrame";
addChild(newFrame);
```

So far everything is OK but later on

```
addChildAt(textClip,3);
addChildAt(thumbClip,4);
addChildAt(menu,5);
addChildAt(movieFrame,6);
```

Last line gives an errormessage: 1120: Access of undefined property movieFrame.

Comment: Sounds like you have a scoping issue as it looks like you have instantiated your movieclip just fine. Why are you performing `addChild` _and_ `addChildAt`?  You should only need one of those, unless you are removing the movieclip named `movieFrame` from the stage and didn't show that in your code.  Also, where does the second block of code exist? Depending on where that code is located, it will determine if you do in fact have a scoping issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK this is what I did to get things to work. I added empty movieclip in the main timeline and gave instance name "movieFrame". Now the code is almost same than in the original posting.

```
var newFrame:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
newFrame.graphics.lineStyle(lineWidth, xmlData.config.frame.@color);
newFrame.graphics.beginFill(0x000000, 0);
newFrame.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, stage.stageWidth+2, stage.stageHeight+2);
newFrame.graphics.endFill();
movieFrame.addChild(newFrame);
```

And now all the addChildAt commands work OK. Thanks for helping me to get on the right rail once again.

Answer (score 0):

This little error means that you haven't correctly created the `instance` of your `class` when invoked using the `new` operator.

```
var movieFrame:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
addChildAt(movieFrame, 6);
```

or

```
var movieFrame:MyClass = new MyClass();
addChildAt(movieFrame, 6);
```

**Edit**

The propriety `name` of an instance as `first argument` of `addChild` or `addChildAt` methods provokes your error message.

```
var newFrame:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
newFrame.name = "movieFrame";
addChild(movieFrame);
```

Compiler error:

> 1120: Access of undefined property movieFrame.

Comment: He has instantiated the movieclip just fine.  The line `newFrame.name = "movieFrame"` sets the instance name of the movieclip.  The weird thing is that there are two 'addChild' types of calls going on which leads me to believe that he is trying to access the same movieclip from two _different_ places in the code, which could be a scoping issue.

Comment: @Sly Raskal  I didn't know the first argument of `addChild` or `addChildAt` methods could be the propriety `name` of an instance.

Comment: I have used addChild and addChildAt on purpose because the displaylist is reorganized after some events.

Comment: @Sterna The propriety `name` of an instance as `first argument` of `addChildAt` method provokes your error message.

Comment: I don't think so, because all the other addChildAt commands use also name of an instance as first argument. Only difference is the fact that other movie clips are in the main timeline:

Comment: @Sterna But you haven't any proof that another addChildAt works, because of your error message which prevents the code to be executed by the compiler. Dont use the name property for addChild, and you'll see that it works.

Comment: If I take that one command away all the other addChildAt commands are OK, tested few hundred times.

Comment: That is ridiculous, the name of an instance cannot be used to reference directly an object of any kind. You reference an object by a variable or object holder of any kind, not by its name property.

Comment: How do you then refer to an object that is already in the display list if not using the name of the object?